# AWS CDK - Use FARGATE_SPOT with ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm using [ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html) in my AWS-CDK project (using Java).

I would like to configure the service to spin up only FARGATE_SPOT instances, but I haven't find any way to do it.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The "mostly experimenting and I don't need stability" is a bit misleading. You can run your workload in production with spot instances and don't need to be in the "experimenting" phase. As long as you architect your solution for this use case (and that's not hard to do) you are good to go.

Comment: I agree, but that was my use case, not everyone's use case. 
It's nowhere written in my question, nor implied, that it's not possible to achieve a production-ready setup using spot instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
    Cluster cluster = new Cluster(...);
    cluster.enableFargateCapacityProviders();

    ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService fargateService = new ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
            this,
            "FargateService",
            ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateServiceProps.builder()
                    .cluster(cluster)
                    .capacityProviderStrategies(
                            singletonList(CapacityProviderStrategy.builder()
                                    .capacityProvider("FARGATE_SPOT")
                                    .weight(1)
                                    .build()
                            ))
                    ....
                    .build());
```